# What does closed luminaire mean

Tags: meaning

I recently bought a [CFL bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_fluorescent_lamp) and it was mentioned in it's box that:

> Not for use in closed luminaire

What does that mean ? Also in this [article](http://www.lrc.rpi.edu/programs/nlpip/lightinganswers/lat5/pc10.asp) they speak about open luminaire also. Would like to know what that is also.

Comment: It needs to be installed in a well-ventilated lamp fitting; presumably because it emits a significant amount of heat.

Comment: Good question for the dictionary!

Comment: "Luminaire" is lighting wonk speak for "light fixture".  A closed fixture would be one, eg, where the bulb is completely surrounded by a globe, or where some other sort of cover is fairly closely fitted to the fixture base, such that air cannot readily circulate.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, Can you add this as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Luminaire" is lighting wonk speak for "light fixture".

A closed fixture would be one, eg, where the bulb is completely surrounded by a globe, or where some other sort of cover is fairly closely fitted to the fixture base, such that air cannot readily circulate:

[image]

An open fixture would allow some air to circulate:

[image]

Comment: Luminaire is **American** lighting wonk speak. In British theatre we speak of a _lantern_.

Comment: But in the general (non-theatrical) British lighting installation industry, *luminaire* is well understood and very widely used, Likewise among architects and designers. A lantern isn't likely to be a **fixture**, even in the theatre, is it?